# How can we enumerate set of partition of integer?

Tags: algorithms

I have following set

$$\mathcal{I}_{k}(n)=\left\{(n_1,\dots,n_k):n_1+\dots+n_k=n,n_{i}\ge n_{i+1}\ge 0\right\}$$

It is easy to write an algorithm which will give us all cases, but I would like to know is there a function, such that

$$\mathcal{I}_{k}(n)=\left\{\varphi(n,k,j):0\le j< M\right\}$$

where $M$ is length of $\mathcal{I}_{k}(n)$ set.

Comment: What do you mean by "function"? You say function but then you write $\varphi$ which tends to be a formula. There certainly is a function with the usual definition since the sets have the same size and thus there is a bijection, the sets are finite and well ordered so you don't even need AC. You probably want something similar to closed form integrals but I can't say I know how that is defined.

Comment: $\varphi$ assigns a certain number to an element of the set. Because set is finite it is obvious that such function exists and it is one to one, but I cannot find way to write it.

Comment: Hmm I don't think you understood exactly what I was trying to say. "Writing" such a function is a broad term. You can define a well ordering on all the possible partitions for each $k$ and $n$ (this is actually easier then writing an (efficient) algorithm) and then you can define the of the function $f(n,k,j)$ to be equal to the $j$'th element in that ordering. But I'm guessing that's still not what you want.

Comment: I want to define a function which makes a one to one connection between $\mathcal{I}_{k}(n)$ and $\{0,1,\dots,M-1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal{I}_k(n)$ be defined as in the OP. Define $\prec_{n,k}\subset \mathcal{I}_k(n)\times\mathcal{I}_k(n)$ as the restriction of the lexicographical ordering on $k$-tuples. Notice that since the lexicographical ordering is linear total and the set $\mathcal{I}_k(n)$ is finite, $\prec_{k,n}$ is a well ordering and thus defines a canonical bijection between $|\mathcal{I}_k(n)|$ and $\mathcal{I}_k(n)$ call this bijection $g_{k,n}$. Then define $f(j,k,n)=g_{k,n}(j)$.

$f$ is the function you want and is fully definable (there is no choice - as in AC - necessary). I don't think this is really what you wanted, but I'm trying to point out that you need to better specify what you mean by write. This is particularly the case since I suspect that what you want can't be done and it's going to be hard to prove that unless you have a rigid definition. The reason I suspect this is that there doesn't seem to be a closed form function even for the size of $\mathcal{I}_k(n)$.